# Error lint en proyecto android

Tags: android

Cuando voy a crear y firmar la apk me aparece este error

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Cuál es la solución?
...

Comment: Significa que tenés errores en el código que necesitás corregir para que el programa compile. En Android Studio debes tener marcas rojas que te indican donde está el error.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo lo que comentas, tu proyecto funciona a la perfección pero cuando intentas firmarlo es cuando surge este problema.

Lo que sucede es que las opciones de `Lint` detectaron "errores" o "warnings" que se escapan al habitual análisis sintáctico que realiza el compilador.

Si al subir tu aplicación directamente a tu dispositivo no tienes algún problema, como opción, en realidad debes agregar lo que especifica el mensaje dentro de tu archivo `/app/build.gradle` , dentro de `android` agrega el bloque `lintOptions` con la siguiente configuración:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias , esto me soluciono el problema

Comment: Excelente @pauuu me da mucho gusto, recuerda que hay que marcar como solución las respuestas de los usuarios de la comunidad que ayuden a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, veo que no has marcado como respuesta aceptada en ninguna de las preguntas que has realizado, revisa [tour], saludos.